# Is it possible not to use Azure ACS authorization server for Sharepoint 2013 apps?

Tags: authentication, azure, sharepoint-2013, azure-acs

I am new in dealing with Sharepoint Server and other office services. Sorry if my question doesn't make sense. My question is:

Can I use other authorization servers other than azure ACS as an access token issuer for Sharepoint 2013 apps ?

I would like to apply OAuth authentication mechanism to the SharePoint sites which are currently accessible by enabling basic authentication of site properties.

SharePoint 2013 supports for server-to-server authentication and app authentication by utilizing and extending the Open Authorization 2.0 (OAuth 2.0)

I am trying to have app authentication to access sharepoint resources(site users) with OAuth mechanism. Is it necessary to register my app on Azure ACS just to get OAuth tokens. Can I also use other auth server which can generate OAuth access token. If yes, how will they app, custom auth server and sharepoint communicate each other?